# My AVPlayer won't pause audio even when I explicitly tell it to pause?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avplayer, avaudiosession

I have this really strange bug after recording video with audio. Upon completion of recording, I go into a different viewController where I play the video, I can get the video to stop(pause) just fine but the audio continues to loop and loop. Even when I go into background mode and come back into foreground, the audio STILL runs! I cannot for the life of me get the audio to stop after the first time I record each video.

The moment I terminate the app and play that video and audio, I CAN get it to pause. Obviously the audio is not being released but I don't understand why not. Is there any way to explicitly pause(stop) all forms of audio from your application? I have tried everything imaginable to stop the audio the first time and nothing I try works.

A side note-- I do get this error sometimes.

"AVAudioSession.mm:646: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session"

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you are doing?